# How to call a Nodejs method in Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, mongoose

I need some help with nodejs and angular, I need to get results with nodejs and display them to HTML with angular. How can I call `user.auth()` from HTML. Here is the code of my controller:

```
     var userModel = require('../models/users');

        var users = {};

        // controller that handles user login request
        users.auth = function (req, res) {

        if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password)
        {
            res.status(400);
            res.send({status:'error',error:'Username or password is missing.'});
        }

        var user = userModel.authUser(req.body.username, req.body.password);

        user.then(function(users){
            res.send(users);
        }, function(){
            res.send({status:'error',error:'Error occured while fetching data from database.'});
        });

    };

module.exports = users;
```

and this is the code in model folder:

```
//Function to auth user baed on username and password.

userModel.authUser = function(username, password){
var results = q.defer();
User.findOne({username: username, password: password},function(err, dbuser) {
    if (err){
        results.reject(err);
    } 


    if(dbuser){

        dbuser.activeSession = makeSessionId();
        dbuser.markModified('string');
        dbuser.save(function(err, dbuser){
            var response = {};

            response.status = 'success';
            response.sessionId = dbuser.activeSession;
            response.username = dbuser.username;
            results.resolve(response);
        });


    } else{
        var response = {};
        response.status = 'error';
        response.error = 'Invalid username or password';
        results.resolve(response);  
    }
});

return results.promise;
}
```

I need to call these methods from HTML file, but I don't know how. I am not allowed to use `.ejs.`

Comment: I think you should read a little on REST and making and consuming services with node.js and angula. This seems like a good tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/node-and-angular-to-do-app-controllers-and-services

Basically you need to make a http request from angular and expose an endpoint in your node.js application. You can read the tutorial I sent you to see how exactly you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to the problem is to create routes for these methods in your node.js app. After creating routes, hit those URLs using `$http` from your angular app. This will invoke methods in your node.js application.